# What's the equivalent of jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(fn) in sinonjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, jasmine2.0, sinon-chai

I'm looking for the equivalent of `jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(fn)` in sinonjs.

For example:

```
const mySpy = jasmine.createSpy('my spy')
.and
.callFake((options) => Object.assign({}, {name: 'foo'}, options));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A spy that can modify the return value (of the optional wrapped function) is called a *stub* in Sinon parlance, so what you are looking for [is the documentation on stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.4/stubs/). Your example would look like this:

```
const myStub = sinon.stub().callsFake((options) => Object.assign({}, {name: 'foo'}, options));

console.log(myStub().name === 'foo') // => 'true'
```

Disclosure: I am part of the Sinon maintainer team.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the Jasmine documentation, this should do something similar:

```
const mySpy = sinon.spy((options) => Object.assign({}, {name: 'foo'}, options))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method", func);
```

Check this out: http://legacy.sinonjs.org/docs/

Comment: That method signature has been deprecated since version 2. You now use `callsFake` to do the same: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.4/stubs/. Otherwise fine, but remember that there is no object and no method in the askers question.